# Filtering an array of strings based on a character in the string

Tags: javascript, typescript

As a long time dabbler in VBA I'm now having a look at Typescript.

I have an array of strings

Each string is a binary number

I wish to filter the array to obtain all those strings that have a '1' at position X

I can write a normal function to do the job

```
    function CountOnes( ipArray: string[], ipIndex: number): number
    {
        var myCount:number=0
        for (var ipString of ipArray)
        {
            if (ipString[ipIndex]==="1") { myCount+=1}
        }
        return myCount
    }
```

but I cannot seem to achieve the same using the .filter method (myData is the array of strings, myIndex is the character position)

```
    myCount = myData.filter((x:string, myIndex:number) => x[myIndex]==="1").length)
```

What am I not understanding?  Please feel free to propose a .reduce method based solution.

Please be aware that from a coding perspective I can achieve the above goal using a filter methodin both VBA and nim (VBA required me to write a FilterIt class) so I'm a bit perplexed as to why I can't achieve my goal in Typescript/javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just a few things: the second argument to the closure you pass to `filter` is the index of the element `x`, not the index you want to check for. And second, you've got a stray closing bracket in there.

This would do the trick:

```
const myIndex = 3;
const myCount = myData.filter((x: string) => x[myIndex]==="1").length;
```

Note how the closure captures `myIndex` from the surrounding scope.

Or, using `reduce`:

```
const myIndex = 3;
const myCount = myData.reduce((count: number, x: string) => count += x[myIndex] === "1" ? 1 : 0, 0);
```

Comment: I should add: the `reduce` approach is probably preferred as it doesn't have to allocate a new array like `filter` does.

Comment: Both the filter and the Reduce examples use a variable in an anonymous function that isn't declared in the params section of the function.  Is that correct?  Also, I can follow 'count += x[myIndex] === "1" ? 1 : 0' but I don't see where the final ',0' comes from.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Although, I guess, they're closures, not merely anonymous functions. You can read all about how closures work in JS [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures). As for the second point, `reduce` needs an initial value to "reduce into", so to speak. To reduce a list of strings into a single number, reduce needs to know what number to start with. That initial value is the final argument to `reduce`, in this case `0`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this version:

```
 function CountOnes( ipArray: string[], ipIndex: number): number
    {
        var myCount:number=0
        for (var ipString of ipArray)
        {
            if (ipString[ipIndex]==="1") { myCount+=1}
        }
        return myCount
    }
```

For the array: `["01000", "00111", "110000"]`

In the above code, `ipIndex` is the one you pass. However, in the `filter` function

```
 myCount = myData.filter((x:string, myIndex:number) => x[myIndex]==="1").length)
```

`myIndex` is the index of the string `x` in the array `myData`. That's why you are getting incorrect output. Try this:

```
function CountOnes( ipArray: string[], ipIndex: number): number
    {
        return ipArray.filter((x:string) => x[ipIndex]==="1").length)
    }
```